# Angularjs:SyntaxError: Unexpected token ' in JSON at position 97 at JSON.parse

Tags: angularjs, json

This is my output

```
{"contacts":[{"id":"1","company":"Cutting","contact":"Russell Chimera"},{"id":"2","company":"Gge\'s","contact":"Marci"}]}
```

I got this error

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token ' in JSON at position 97 at JSON.parse

I tried to print it like `{{x.company}}` or `{{x.company | escape}}` but problem remain same. I try to print company name `"Gge's"`. I don't want to remove single quote from company name.
Can anyone please help me to find solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your scope variable `x` should hold the value of `data.contacts[1]`, to get the value of `Gge's` with single quote from company name. There is no such scenario in AngularJS where it omits the single quote from the JSON value. Be sure of your JSON again.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
   var data = {
    "contacts":[
     {
       "id":"1","company":"Cutting","contact":"Russell Chimera"
     },
     {
       "id":"2","company":"Gge\'s","contact":"Marci"
     }
    ]
   };
   $scope.x = data.contacts[1];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  {{x.company}}
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Ankit for reply. But My issue comes when i got data through get $http.get("contact").then(function(response) {
        $scope.contact = response.data.contacts;
    });

Comment: If i copy same response and use directly as shown in your reply. it's working fine.

Comment: Is there anything wrong in my code so that i can't get it by $http.get()?

Comment: Thanks. this is working.There was an issue in my json_encode  array value.

Comment: @Deepak3301086 glad to help you

Answer (score 4):

You must know that the JSON key "contacts", has a JSON array as its value. to access your value "Gge\'s", you will have to access,

```
x = data.contacts[1].company;
```

where your data is :

```
data = {"contacts":[{"id":"1","company":"Cutting","contact":"Russell Chimera"},{"id":"2","company":"Gge\'s","contact":"Marci"}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check this :"Gge\'s" . Please try to put unicode of ' this then try to parse it then it will resolve the problem.

Comment: I tried "Gge&#39;s". but i will print Gge&#39;s not Gge's

Comment: try this , i just removed \{
  "id": "2",
  "company": "Gge's",
  "contact": "Marci"
 }  also use https://jsonlint.com/    to verify your json

Comment: from controller it is print like '{ "id": "2", "company": "Gge's", "contact": "Marci" }' . Due to this i need to put backslash \. I removed \ it but it is not work.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I just removed commented lines in JSON file(post in postman) as JSON won't take comments in them.